# 2 errors with Zabbix Server

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, zabbix

I have two problem with Zabbix server and Zabbix agent. The selector (ZBX) is red and I have 2 errors.

[image]

[image]

How can I resolve this two problems and change the selector to green.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to also list what you have attempted or investigated so far - that would allow to concentrate on a specific problem.

In this case, following [the troubleshooting steps](https://zabbix.org/wiki/Troubleshooting#Zabbix_says_.22Agent_unreachable.22.2C_but_the_host_is_up._How_do_I_debug_that.3F) might be the best idea.

Comment: Now I have one error, which is 111. Firewall is down, telnet ports are open. Can it depend on the version? If the server has version 4.0, and agent 3.0.6? and with which command I can remove one version and replace another.